# Find column index of maximum element for each layer of 3d numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 3D NumPy array `arr`. Here is an example:

```
>>> arr
array([[[0.05, 0.05, 0.9 ],
        [0.4 , 0.5 , 0.1 ],
        [0.7 , 0.2 , 0.1 ],
        [0.1 , 0.2 , 0.7 ]],

       [[0.98, 0.01, 0.01],
        [0.2 , 0.3 , 0.95],
        [0.33, 0.33, 0.34],
        [0.33, 0.33, 0.34]]])
```

For each layer of the cube (i.e., for each matrix), I want to find the index of the column containing the largest number in the matrix. For example, let's take the first layer:

```
>>> arr[0]
array([[0.05, 0.05, 0.9 ],
       [0.4 , 0.5 , 0.1 ],
       [0.7 , 0.2 , 0.1 ],
       [0.1 , 0.2 , 0.7 ]])
```

Here, the largest element is `0.9`, and it can be found on the third column (i.e. index 2). In the second layer, instead, the max can be found on the first column (the largest number is `0.98`, the column index is 0).

The expected result from the previous example is:

```
array([2, 0])
```

Here's what I have done so far:

```
tmp = arr.max(axis=-1)
argtmp = arr.argmax(axis=-1)
indices = np.take_along_axis(
    argtmp,
    tmp.argmax(axis=-1).reshape((arr.shape[0], -1)),
    1,
).reshape(-1)
```

The code above works, but I'm wondering if it can be further simplified as it seems too much complicated from my point of view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the maximum in each column before applying `argmax`:

```
arr.max(-2).argmax(-1)
```

Reducing the column to a single maximum value will not change which column has the largest value. Since you don't care about the row index, this saves you a lot of trouble.

Comment: Oooh I feel so stupid now that I look at your solution!! Thanks a lot, super useful!!